# maven resources are not getting included

Tags: java, maven

When I click on "update maven project", resources are not included. When we look at the resources build path, it is shown as **

### pom.xml

```xml
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>lib/config</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

### Question

Why my maven resources are not getting included ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>lib/config</directory>
           </resource>
</resources>
```